# iTunes Reporter download subscriptions data for a specific date

Tags: app-store-connect

However it is for me possible to set up and run the Reporter tool for iTunes Connect, I seem not be able to run Detailed Reports and I cannot find a way how to retrieve the data for Subscriptions in the same way as on the webpage for iTunes Connect.

Summary Sales Reports with Sales.getReport of type Summary work fine:

```
java.exe -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.getReport 8xxxxxxx, Sales, Summary, monthly, 201605
```

But Detailed Reports do not work:

```
java.exe -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.getReport 8xxxxxxx, Sales, Detailed, Weekly, 20170101
```

The other thing is to be able to get the subscriptions data to a specific date, e.g. number of subscribers on 12.11.2016.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notes to self (and those researching reporter tool usage):

I find, overall, for the ever changing reporter tool, the Apple documentation lacks details. For instance in regards to properties file, the Access Token worked before (few day ago) with the argument "Password=" now it is needed to be set to "AccessToken=", however, in the documentation you won´t find guideline how to set properly the Properties File´s Arguments, and, after downloading the reporter 2.1 you realise that the  properties file contains the argument "Password=" as well.

Addressing the Subscription reporting, the new Reporter User Guide dated 18.7.2017 contains information how to do this, for Subscriptions and Subscribers, and works fine for me. For completeness, here a piece of code for someone behind a company´s firewall using proxy would run:

```
java -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=portNumber -Dhttps.proxyUser=proxyUsername -Dhttps.proxyPassword=proxyPassword -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.getReport VendorNumber, Subscription, Summary, Daily, 20170105
```

The above code returns a summary with all running subscription on the selected day.

Otherwise, before running the above code or when problems occur, one clould also check the availability of the reporter service with get status command:

```
java -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyHost -Dhttps.proxyPort=portNumber -Dhttps.proxyUser=proxyUsername -Dhttps.proxyPassword=proxyPassword -jar Reporter.jar p=Reporter.properties m=Normal Sales.getStatus
```

with the positive outcome "Sales and Trends Reporter is currently available."

Comment: I am really grateful to see this syntax being used. I've been trying to get my reporter working in the same way using these -D settings, and almost 4 years later. Sadly mine returns "Network not available." Gives me hope that this solution worked once upon a time, though!